# Boundary of Seifert Fibered Space is a $T^2$ or $K^2$

Tags: low-dimensional-topology, manifolds-with-boundary

I'm getting my feet wet with Seifert Fibered Spaces in Hatcher's 3-manifold papers. [Elsewhere](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1202.4142.pdf), it is said that this follows easily from the definition. I am not seeing it. I think we would need to know that $T^2$ and $K^2$ are the only surfaces which have a foliation of circles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both surfaces can be described foliating over a (the yellow) circle as a base (the  Zerlegung) by circles (in reds and blues). In the picture
[image]
the "leaves" (in reds and blues) meet the base in yellow. The edges of the squares are identified regarding the specified letters and the directions of them the get $T$ and $K$ respectively.

Comment: This is a nice illustration of the fibration of these surfaces, thank you. Is there an argument as to why Seifert Fibered 3-manifolds cannot have *other* kinds of boundary components?

Comment: The boundaries of a SFS come from the boundary components of the orbit surface which are circles, over them -fibering- gives these two kind of borders.